# Getting a deserialing error when getting from the Wordpress rest API, unexpected { in [0].title

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, wordpress-rest-api

We are creating an application in Xamarin that is aimed at the Android market. 
We need to pull a list of objects off of the Wordpress API in order to populate a list view.

The code seems to be erroring at the deserialisation part of the code.
EventLW is a ListView on the front-end of the application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace StudioDen.View
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Events : ContentPage
    {
        public Events()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetProducts();

        }

        private async void GetProducts()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://studioden.uk/wp-json/wp/v2/events/");

            var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Events>>(response);
            eventLV.ItemsSource = events;
        }
    }
}
```

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
>     Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '[0].title', line 1, position 341.

[image]

Any ideas on what is going wrong here? I followed a youtube tutorial and I don't think it is an issue with the code directly but with the Json string from the call.

Comment: Where ContentPage is defined? As I can see you are trying to deserialize your json into a list of Events (which derive from ContentPage).

Could you provide ContentPage definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deserializing the response object and not the response content. The following is what you need to do

```
private async void GetProducts()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await 
    client.GetAsync("http://studioden.uk/wpjson/wp/v2/events/");

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
         var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
         var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Events>>(content);
     }
     else
     {
         //Do stuff based on the status, was the content found, 
         //was there a server error etc.
     }
    ...
}
```

**Explanation on the above code**

You send a request and get a response object which includes headers, status code, messages etc.

you check that the request is successful(if it isn't you want to handle a bad request or server error etc)

you then need to read the response content into a string then deserialize the json in that string value. before finally populating your list view

Comment: Is there a "using" statement I would need for the IsSuccessStatusCode part? it says because the response is a string, it doesn't have that extension.

Comment: Nevermind, I changed client.GetStringAsync to client.GetAsync and it removed those errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure that the `API Response` is in a `JSON` format , otherwise ,  make it in `JSON` format, first, and then all the problems will be solved .
You can take the `Content` of the object for example.

More specifically , you have to be sure that you are going to `Deserialize` a `string` that it is in `JSON` format.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to parse the JSON data to it
and it needs to have definitions for the data you are getting

so this class for the data you are getting should be

```
public class Event
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string date_gmt { get; set; }
    public guid guid { get; set; }
    public string modified { get; set; }
    public string modified_gmt { get; set; }
    public string slug { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public title title { get; set; }
    public content content { get; set; }
    public string featured_media { get; set; }
    public string template { get; set; }
}

public class guid
{
    public string rendered { get; set; }
}

public class title
{
    public string rendered { get; set; }
}
public class content
{
    public string rendered { get; set; }
    public string @protected { get; set; } //@ to ignore the keyword protected
}
```

also, change your client code to this

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("http://studioden.uk/wpjson/wp/v2/events/").ConfigureAwait(false);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
         var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var events = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Event>>(content);
    }
```

Here The class Event is used to map the JSON data to it so you can access it later from the list

**Note:** You shouldn't expose the Endpoint here in your question
that's how I saw the data and wrote the class for it

Comment: I used JSON2CSHARP [link](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp) to create my classes. I changed my client code to what you described and "IsSuccessStatusCode" isn't an extensible from response.

Comment: My bad, I just edited my answer. PS: include Infos like these "I used JSON2CSHARP link to create my classes" in your future question. cause trust me, people on this site are brutal when it comes to unclear question or missing info